# How to rearrange a view according to the size of a label?

Tags: ios, view, autosize

I have a label in a view setted with an autosize with the next code:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[labelsizeToFit];
```

My problem is the next:

[image: Example]

When the label is smaller or bigger, the rest of labels are separated from this or overlaped each other.

How can I do to rearrange views (buttons, labels, etc.) automatically?

Thank you from a begginer iOS developer.

Comment: I believe you can use Auto Layout constraints. Related SO answer eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331900/ios-autolayout-keep-distance-from-2-views

Answer (score 0):

Get frame of first label and then manage other labels or views accordingly. Like this:

```
UILabel *firstLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 30)];
[firstLbl setText:@"Any Text"];
[firstLbl sizeToFit];

CGRect frame = firstLbl.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.size.height + frame.origin.y + 10;
UILabel *nextLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Try this.